# How to show NextImage in ImageView when User SwipeLeft in ImageView through UISwipeGestureRecognizer in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i am Newbie in iOS Development. i want to make an application in my application i make one UIScrollview and in this UIScrollView i add an UIImageview. when viewDidAppear i set imageview image like as

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagelink=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
NSLog(@"imageLink %@",imagelink);
[self.bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelink] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}
```

And a code to add a Gesture for my Imageview and Scrollvie like as

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeftdirection=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:)];
swipeGestureLeftdirection.delegate=self;
swipeGestureLeftdirection.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.bigImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeftdirection];
[self.bigScrollview addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeftdirection];

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRightdirection=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToRighttWithGestureRecognizer:)];
swipeGestureRightdirection.delegate=self;
swipeGestureRightdirection.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.bigImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRightdirection];
[self.bigScrollview addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRightdirection];
```

Here Self.bigimage is my UIImageview and self.bigScrollview is my UIScrollView.
Now i want when User Swipe left then i want UIImageview image as self.imagesa next index and when swipe right then i want UIImageVIew image back index image how it possible. Please give me Solution for it.

Comment: show your UISwipeGestureRecognizer action

Comment: @Sport UISwipeGestureRecognizer action
    -(void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
    for(index=0;index<[self.imagesa count];index++)
    {
        self.bigImage.image=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index+1];
    }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do no use loop inside, slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:

write code like this

```
 -(void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{ 
     if(index<[self.imagesa count])
     {
         NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *imagelink=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        NSLog(@"imageLink %@",imagelink);
       [self.bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelink] placeholderImage:        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];

    index++;
   }
 }
```

make index as global vairable, on viewDidLoad initailize with 0.

```
  -(void)slideToRighttWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
   { 
      if(index>0)
     {
        index--;
        NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *imagelink=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        NSLog(@"imageLink %@",imagelink);
       [self.bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelink] placeholderImage:        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];


    }
 }
```

Comment: But bro here my array is Contain Image URL Link.so i write like as 
   NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *imagelink=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    NSLog(@"imageLink %@",imagelink);
    [self.bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelink] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    index++;
But it shows error in line   NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];

Comment: bro , i have modified my answer, see once more, if this could help you.

Comment: Here my imageview is inside my Scrollview so i add a SWipeGesture to my Imageview but your code is not work can i add a Swipegesture to my Scrollview then it is work?

Comment: can you post the code of, adding gesture on scrollview

Comment: you scrollview having one image at a time or multiple images ?

Comment: Only One image at a time.

Comment: same code is working at my pc. please see if, IBOutlet is set for bigImage

Comment: initially i set index int variable and i set its value is 0 it is right or wrong?

Comment: i got it your code is right but Sorry for take your time.